Question on Tonelli theorem for series.
I am thinking to proove tonelli theorem for series using monotone convergence theorem.
$$\sum_{j\geq1}\sum_{i\geq1} a_{ij}=\sum_{i\geq 1}\sum_{j\geq1} a_{ij}.$$
Where $a_{ij}\geq0$.
I am thinking to use counting measure
And define $f_n(m)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{ij}\right)\chi_{\{n\}}$
Then integrating over naturals with respect to counting measure and using monotone convergence theorem we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{N}} f_n(m) d\mu=\int_{\mathbb{N}} \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(m) d\mu.$$
Integral on right hand side is our $\sum_{i\geq 1}\sum_{j\geq1} a_{ij}.$
This is the only way I am able to think to utilise this theorem, how can I proceed further from this.

Define $f_i(j)=a_{ij}$ for $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$. We have by the monotone convergence theorem with $\mu$ the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$
\begin{align}
 \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_\mathbb{N} f_i(j) \,d\mu(j) &= \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^N \int_\mathbb{N} f_i(j) \,d\mu(j) \\
 &= \lim_{N\to\infty} \int_\mathbb{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f_i(j) \,d\mu(j) \\
 &\stackrel{MC}{=} \int_\mathbb{N} \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^N f_i(j) \,d\mu(j) \\
 &= \int_\mathbb{N} \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(j) \,d\mu(j).
\end{align}
The integrals with respect to the counting measure are just series, so we have:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty f_i(j) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(j)$$
and therefore
$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}.$$
